# Android: How to read NFC tag with current app

Tags: android, nfc

I'm writing an app which needs to read NFC tags. Rather than the act of reading the tag opening up a new app via intent filters I would like my currently open app to simply read a nearby tag.

I have tried to use enableForegroundDispatch() but with no luck. Whenever an NFC tag is present my device simply opens up the standard "Tags" app instead.

The code I have so far is:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
String[][] techList = new String[][]{};
filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
try {
    filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
} catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Check your mime type.");
}
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
```

(Which is basically copied from a tutorial that I found).

Does anyone know if this is the right way of going about this?
How can I prevent the standard "Tags" app from opening up instead of my own app receiving the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent.

Thanks

Comment: What data do you have on your tag? Do you want to trigger upon a certain tag type (see the `android.nfc.tech.*` namespace) or upon any tag?

Comment: The only thing I need (and I think the only thing on the tag) is the ID

Comment: This does not really answer my question.

Comment: Ok, sorry... The tag type is MifareClassic so I probably want to trigger on that only. I am only interested in the tag ID.

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently registers the foreground dispatch system to trigger only upon NFC tags that contain an NDEF Text record (or a "text/plain" MIME type record). Thus, if your tag does not contain such a record, the NFC discovery event is passed to other apps (or in your case handled by the standard Tags app).

Therefore, you might want to register the foreground dispatch system for an intent that fits your tag:

```
IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
String[][] techList = new String[][]{ new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() } };
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
```

Or you could just register to trigger upon any tag:

```
adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, null, null);
```